# Filtering items in list view using query string - FilterName & FilterMultiValue 32 values limit?

Tags: list-view, query-string, filter, filtermulivalue

Basically what I am trying to do is to filter list view using query string parameters FilterName=ID & FilterMultiValue=1;2;3;...

Let say we have list with default view. We want to filter items in this view by ids. URL will look like this:

```
http://server/sites/bla/Lists/MyListWithItems/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=ID&FilterMultiValue=2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;
```

1. We have 32 ids in query string param - This shows correct items on the first page but on next pages items are not filtered.
2. If I add one more item id to FilterMultiValue param (in total 33 ids in query string param) items are not filtered at all. Is like the parameter and values in FilterMultiValue are ignored.

Have anyone encountered this issue before? Is this bug in list view web part or am I doing something wrong here?

I tried to use Query String (URL) filter web part connected to list view web part but I couldn't make it to filter by multiple values.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same question. can someone please help us.

Comment: According to tech support :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ef3e75b5-197f-4409-9d52-4acf3a0a8c97/filtering-items-in-list-view-using-query-string-filtername-filtermultivalue-32-values-limit?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious
There is no possibility to disable limit of 32 ids and next page with filtering will not work.